# How to change +5 more text to custom text in full calendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I want to change the More text(+4 More) to custom text(like More events) in full calendar. Please refer the attached image below.

Example: If the day having more than three or two events full calendar plugin adding +More events on the particular day, I want to change the text to More Events.

[image: a busy cat]

```
var fullcalendarId = $('.wellness');

var options = {
  header: {
    left: '',
    center: 'title',
    right: ''
  },
  columnHeaderFormat: 'dddd',
  navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
  editable: true,
  eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
  eventLimitText: function() {
      return "More Events"
  },
  disableDragging: true,
  eventMouseover: function( event, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
      var event_date = event.start._i;
      $('.fc-day-grid-event').css({ 'background':'#ffffff', }); 
      $( this ).css({ 'background':'#f7f7f7' });
      var offset = $( this ).offset();
      var eventHeight = $( this ).outerHeight();
      var fullcalendarId = 'fitness-wellness';
      var findValue = $(this).parents('.tab-pane.active').attr('id');
      if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 991px)').matches){}
      else{
        eventContent(event.id, offset.left, offset.top, eventHeight, event_date, fullcalendarId);
      }  
  },
  eventMouseout: function( event, jsEvent, view ) { 

  },
  eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
      var event_date = calEvent.start._i;
      var offset = $( this ).offset();
      var eventHeight = $( this ).outerHeight();
      var eventId = calEvent.id;
      var fullcalendarId = 'fitness-wellness';
      var findValue = $(this).parents('.tab-pane.active').attr('id');
      if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 991px)').matches){}else{
        eventContent(calEvent.id, offset.left, offset.top, eventHeight, event_date, fullcalendarId);
      }
  },
  dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view, resourceObj) {
      if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 991px)').matches){
          $('.fc-past, .fc-future').css('background-color', 'transparent');
          $(this).css('background-color', '#d5d5d5');
          var eventDate = date.format();
          dayclickEventMobile(eventDate);
      }else{ }      
  },
  events: globalEventsFitness 
}

fullcalendarId.fullCalendar(options);
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please show us

Comment: you can reference to https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventLimitText

Comment: @ Carsten Løvbo Andersen I have added my code.

Comment: @TanBoonJun, I dont know how to add the eventLimitText in the code, can you please check my code.

Comment: Thanks TanBoonJun its working. I have updated my code.

Comment: so now you've updated your code, is it working? If so, you should have added it as an Answer, below. Because now your question makes no sense, if you ask us about code which already works.

Answer (score 4):

Here it is with Fullcalendar v5+:

```
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('myDiv');
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    ....
    dayMaxEvents: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    dayMaxEvents: 2, // for all non-TimeGrid views
    // views: {
    //     timeGrid: {
    //         dayMaxEventRows: 6, // adjust to 6 only for timeGridWeek/timeGridDay
    //         dayMaxEvents: 2 // adjust to 6 only for timeGridWeek/timeGridDay
    //     }
    // },
    moreLinkContent:function(args){
        return '+'+args.num+' More items';
    },
    ....
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
moreLinkContent:function(args){
             let count_element = document.createElement('span');
             count_element.setAttribute('style', 'font-size: 16px;');
             count_element.innerHTML = 'More Events';
            return {
                domNodes:[count_element],
            }
         }
```

Comment: It could help kishan Borsadiya if you try to add some additional comments explaining the changes and why.